# Redirigir localhost a dominio xampp

Tags: php, windows, servidor, xampp

Estoy intentando redirigir localhost de xampp a una carpeta dentro de htdocs de xampp de la siguiente forma

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts `Añadir:` **127.0.0.1 dominio.com**

> D:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf `Añadir:`

```html
<VirtualHost dominio.com:80>
 ServerName dominio.com
 ServerAlias dominio.com
 DocumentRoot D:/xampp/htdocs/ejemplo
</VirtualHost>
```

El error que me aparece es:

> La página **dominio.com** no puede procesar esta solicitud ahora.

> HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Los errores 500 son errores de servidor, posiblemente en el script al que estás redirigiendo. Revisa dicho script o el log de errores. Un error 500 se puede producir por algo tan simple como un signo cualquier de más o de menos, por olvidar cerrar una línea de código con `;` etc...

Comment: Pero es extraño, ya que accediendo de a localhost/carpeta/index.php, funciona perfectamente

Comment: @Pelukosa tienes activado el **vhosts_alias** en el archivo httpd.conf de apache ? esto es un servicio de apache que hay que activar.
Mira que no este así `#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` si esta con la almohadilla quítasela

Answer (score 0):

Para configurar en Xampp un dominio personal y que vaia directamente a una carpeta hago lo siguiente:

1. Nos vamos a el fichero de configuración **hosts** de Windows

   `127.0.0.1 dominio.com`
2. Nos vamos a mirar el modulo de vhosts de Xampp, que esta en
   `c:\xampp\apache\conf` y comprovamos que la línea **Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf** no este comentada con una almoadilla
3. Por último iremos en la carpeta de extra dentro de la ruta donde se encontraba el fichero httpd.conf encontramos el fichero de configuración de virtual hosts **httpd-vhosts.conf** y configuraremos nuestro dominio virtual alli de la siguiente manera.

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\ejemplo"
        ServerName dominio.com
        ServerAlias dominio.com
   </VirtualHost>
   ```